# Как использовать предикат для двух методов?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Дан класс надо для метода findBy и isBinary написать общий метод с предикатом , чтобы убрать дублирование кода .    Один метод я сделал , не знаю как написать метод isBinary т.к он возвращает булеан Буду благодарен за подсказку.

```
public class Tree<E> implements SimpleTree<E> {

    private final Node<E> root;

    Tree(final E root) {
        this.root = new Node<>(root);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E parent, E child) {
        boolean rsl = false;
        if (!findBy(child).isPresent()) {
            Node<E> temp = findBy(parent).get();
            if (temp != null) {
                temp.children.add(new Node<E>(child));
                rsl = true;
            }
        }
        return rsl;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Node<E>> findBy(E value) {

        return findByPredicate((x) -> x.value.equals(value));
    }

    public boolean isBinary() {
        boolean result = true;
        Queue<Node<E>> data = new LinkedList<>();
        data.offer(this.root);
        while (!data.isEmpty()) {
            Node<E> el = data.poll();
            if (el.children.size() <= 2) {
                data.addAll(el.children);
            } else {
                result = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

    private Optional<Node<E>> findByPredicate(Predicate<Node<E>> condition) {
        Optional<Node<E>> rsl = Optional.empty();
        Queue<Node<E>> data = new LinkedList<>();
        data.offer(this.root);
        while (!data.isEmpty()) {
            Node<E> el = data.poll();
            if (condition.test(el)) {
                rsl = Optional.of(el);
                break;
            }
            data.addAll(el.children);
        }
        return rsl;
    }

}


public interface SimpleTree<E> {

    boolean add(E parent, E child);

    Optional<Node<E>> findBy(E value);

    class Node<E> {
        final E value;
        final List<Node<E>> children = new ArrayList<>();

        public Node(E value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}

    @Test
    public void when6ElFindLastThen6() {
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(1);
        tree.add(1, 2);
        tree.add(1, 3);
        tree.add(1, 4);
        tree.add(4, 5);
        tree.add(5, 6);
        assertThat(tree.findBy(6).isPresent(), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void when6ElFindNotExitThenOptionEmpty() {
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(1);
        tree.add(1, 2);
        assertThat(tree.findBy(7).isPresent(), is(false));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenTreeBinary() {
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(1);
        tree.add(1, 2);
        tree.add(1, 3);
        tree.add(2, 4);
        tree.add(2, 5);
        tree.add(3, 6);
        tree.add(3, 7);
        assertThat(tree.isBinary(), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenNotBinary() {
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(1);
        tree.add(1, 2);
        tree.add(1, 3);
        tree.add(2, 4);
        tree.add(2, 5);
        tree.add(3, 6);
        tree.add(3, 7);
        tree.add(3, 8);
        assertThat(tree.isBinary(), is(false));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `findByPredicate`, чтобы определить есть ли узел с более чем двумя детьми. Если есть - значит дерево не бинарное:

```
public boolean isBinary() {
   return !(findByPredicate((el) -> el.children.size() > 2)).isPresent();
}
```